# Как сделать асинхронный поиск? AioHttp

Tags: python, веб-программирование, aiohttp

**Всем привет! Как сделать асинхронный поиск?**

Допустим у меня есть таблица в БД, и я хочу выполнить по ней поиск, без перезагрузки страницы.
Допустим, я ввожу в поисковую строку на сайте какое-либо слово, и мне сразу высветится какая-нибудь подсказка по поиску с этим словом.

Comment: На стороне клиента (браузер) использовать ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лирическое отступление: обычно под асинхронным поиском, особенно при упоминании асинхронного бэкэнд-фреймворка вроде aiohttp, подразумевается некий соответствующий алгоритм, который выполняется параллельно в СУБД. Асинхронность же на клиентской стороне реализовать значительно проще, даже Flask с этим спокойно справится; в зависимости от RPC, конечно. Вам просто надо кидать запросы с фронтэнда на сервер, и желательно немного оптимизировать, чтобы не убить сервер.

### Вариант 1, велосипед

Сделайте на клиентской стороне поле для ввода, изменения которого отслеживаются кодом (для сайтов это будет JavaScript) и отправляются на сервер как поисковая строка.

Здесь важно продумать оптимизации, например:

1. На сервере кэшировать результаты.
2. На клиенте слать запросы не чаще, например, раза в секунду.
3. На клиенте также можно использовать старые результаты запросов, т.к чаще всего это будут префиксы текущего запроса, содержащие нужные данные, и их можно профильтровать на клиенте.

Вполне вероятно, что для этого есть готовые библиотечки, облегчающие жизнь, хотя бы для клиентской стороны, их *вдумчивое* использование ускорит разработку и вероятно повысит её качество.

### Вариант 2, сторонние сервисы

Есть различные сервисы, которые помогают решать проблему поиска по сайту. В простейшем виде можно попробовать прикрутить Google-поиск, из вариантов мощнее есть специализированные SaaS, использующиеся для создания почковых строк на сайтах с крупными базам знаний или онлайн-ретейла. Примеры: [Searchanise](https://start.searchanise.com), [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com).